# How can scroll ViewPage smoothly?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a ViewPager which contain three Fragments, each Fragment contain a ListView, then when I add some images to the ListView, scroll the ViewPager is not smoothly, and the adapter extends FragmentPageAdapter. How should I do?

Comment: post your getView of listiew

Comment: Thanks, the problem is from getView. Because the ListView height is "wrap_content", so when scrolling to other page, Framework will call getView very much, when I change the height is "mactch_parent" and it's scroll smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting ListView layout_height is "match_parent" or "fill_parent" may resolve this problem.